# I use dingo/api in laravel.But it's always error 404

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, dingo-api

I use dingo/api in laravel.But it's always error 404.
This is my config file:

```
# dingo/api`  
API_STANDARDS_TREE=vnd  
API_SUBTYPE=ipr  
API_PREFIX=api  
API_VERSION=v1  
API_DEBUG=true
```

And ,in my `config/app.php`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REFrQ.png)

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
// RepositoryServiceProvider
Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
// Dingo
Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class
```

Also, I have generated `routes/api.php` by 
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider"`

This is My `routes\api.php` :

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {

    $api->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Home'], function($api) {
        $api->get('/test', 'ULoginController@register');

    });
});
```

This is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3tqk.png)

I need your help, Thanks.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:800/api/test` in my postman uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$api->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Home'], function($api) {
    $api->get('/test', 'ULoginController@register');

});
```

To

```
$api->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Home'], function($api) {
    $api->get('/test', 'App\Http\Controllers\ULoginController@register');

});
```

Why? Because Dingo uses a separate logic for loading controllers to differentiate between Laravel and Dingo API's controller.

That's why you have to manually call the controller path

Comment: It's not work. But when I visit 127.0.0.1:800/api/api/test, It's work! Why？I'm a little confused.

Comment: Because you have prefix `API_PREFIX=api` remove that

Comment: You are right. thanks a lot! Besides, thank you for accepting my lameness.